# How to use a type datatable in WHERE clause of a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

Basically I have a C# app that will create a datatable and pass the datatable in as a stored procedure. That all works, however; what I want to do is add logic to the datatable that's passed in.

For example in the below test you'll see a procedure called `RealInsertNewRecords`; this one tries to make sure a duplicate primary key violation does not happen, but I get the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@dataTable"

Below is a complete test, any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

The clarify the stored procedure `RealInsertNewRecords` is what doesn't work

C#

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SQLServer = @"";
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + SQLServer + ";Initial Catalog=myTestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

            sqlCon.Open();
            InsertNewRecords(sqlCon, testTable1());
            InsertNewRecords(sqlCon, testTable2());
            sqlCon.Dispose();
        }

        public static DataTable testTable1()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("myTestPK");

            string[] items = new string[] { "apples", "pears" };

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = items[i];
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return dt;
        }

        public static DataTable testTable2()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("myTestPK");

            string[] items = new string[] { "apples", "pears", "grapes" };

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = items[i];
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return dt;
        }

        public static void InsertNewRecords(SqlConnection sqlCon, DataTable parameterTable)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "InsertNewRecords";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dataTable", parameterTable);
            cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

SQL

```
if exists (select 'x' from sys.databases where [name] = 'myTestDB')
begin
     drop database myTestDB;
end

Create database myTestDB;
GO

USE [myTestDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable]
(
    [myTestPK] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([myTestPK] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

create Type [dbo].myTableParameters as table
(
    myTestPK nvarchar(10)
)
go

create procedure InsertNewRecords(@dataTable [dbo].myTableParameters readonly)
as
begin
    insert into myTable
        select * from @dataTable;
end
go

--This is what i really want to do!
create procedure RealInsertNewRecords(@dataTable [dbo].myTableParameters readonly)
as
begin
    insert into myTable
        select * 
        from @dataTable
        where not exists (select 'x' 
                          from myTable m 
                          where m.myTestPK = @dataTable.myTestPK)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with using a table valued parameter. Rather your SQL is just wrong.

```
insert into myTable
    select * 
    from @dataTable
    where not exists (select 'x' 
                      from myTable m 
                      where m.myTestPK = @dataTable.myTestPK) <-- this line isn't legal
```

You should be using a MERGE statement.

```
MERGE INTO MyTable t USING @dataTable s ON t.myTestPK = s.myTestPK
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (myTestPK) VALUES (s.myTestPK)
; <-- the semicolon is required
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

---

I always name my tables `t` for target and `s` for source. I find it makes it easier to keep track of which is which.

Answer (score -1):

This my not be the best way but I just figured out a way to handle it.  Instead of accessing the DataTable directly insert into a temp table.

```
create procedure InsertNewRecords(@dataTable [dbo].myTableParameters readonly)
as
begin
select * into #InsertNewRecords
from @dataTable;

insert into myTable
select * from #InsertNewRecords
where not exists (select 'x' from [myTable] where [myTable].myTestPK = #InsertNewRecords.myTestPK);
end
go
```